# CarbonKit CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, Viewcontrollers not aligning correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I'm using Carbonkit's CarbonTabSwipeNavigation by ermalkaleci , when the view loads, the viewcontrollers are aligned properly, then when switching to the second viewcontroller the alignment of the second viewcontroller is correct but when scrolling back to the first viewcontroller, it is aligned wrong and a small portion of the second viewcontroller is visible. Tried everything I could find but no luck so far.

My current setup I'm using a toolbar but same behavior when inserting with insertIntoRootViewController :(

```
    class func setupCarbonPages(carbonSwipeTabsItem:CarbonTabSwipeNavigation,tabTitles:[String],totalWidth: CGFloat) -> CarbonTabSwipeNavigation{

    // Setup the default style
    carbonSwipeTabsItem.toolbar.translucent = false
    carbonSwipeTabsItem.setIndicatorColor(AppConfig.BLUECOLOR)
    carbonSwipeTabsItem.setNormalColor(AppConfig.BLUECOLOR)
    carbonSwipeTabsItem.setSelectedColor(AppConfig.BLUECOLOR, font: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14))
    carbonSwipeTabsItem.setTabExtraWidth(CGFloat(0))
    carbonSwipeTabsItem.setNormalColor(AppConfig.BLUECOLOR, font: AppConfig.REGULAR_FONT_16)
    carbonSwipeTabsItem.setSelectedColor(AppConfig.BLUECOLOR, font: AppConfig.REGULAR_FONT_16)

    // Assign tab width & preload all data
    let menuTabItems:UInt = UInt(tabTitles.count)
    let tabWidth = (totalWidth / CGFloat(menuTabItems))
    for index:UInt in 0 ..< menuTabItems {
        carbonSwipeTabsItem.carbonSegmentedControl!.setWidth(tabWidth, forSegmentAtIndex: Int(index))
    }

    return carbonSwipeTabsItem
}
```

Then in my viewcontroller :

```
private func setupSwipableTabs(){
    let width = self.view.frame.width

    carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: menuTabTitles as [AnyObject], toolBar: self.toolBar,delegate: self)
    Helper.setupCarbonPages(carbonTabSwipeNavigation, tabTitles: menuTabTitles, totalWidth: self.view.frame.width).insertIntoRootViewController(self)
    Helper.preloadCarbonPages(carbonTabSwipeNavigation, tabs: 2)
}
```

Library: https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit

[image: Problem]
(Red line is part of the second viewcontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the problem, for some reason the "Clip Subviews" checkbox was unchecked in the misaligning viewcontroller's storyboard. It appeared to have a negative constraint to the left side what was causing the views to misallign and making the viewcontroller clip all subviews forced all subviews to stay in the main viewcontroller's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

try to setup the carbon kit code on main thread

in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
     let width = self.view.frame.width

     carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: menuTabTitles as [AnyObject], toolBar: self.toolBar,delegate: self)
     Helper.setupCarbonPages(carbonTabSwipeNavigation, tabTitles: menuTabTitles, totalWidth:           self.view.frame.width).insertIntoRootViewController(self)
     Helper.preloadCarbonPages(carbonTabSwipeNavigation, tabs: 2)
})
```

Comment: No luck, function gets called in viewDidLoad, tried ViewDidLayoutSubviews but also, no luck :(

Comment: if you are working in view did load, then you must get the screen width in dispatch async

Comment: I will try to find out some other solution

Comment: tried using threads (main&async) but this breaks the whole view, I  noticed tapping on tabs does not have the alignment problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up viewcontroller through storyboard.Set the constraint for the container view as 
 **- Align center x to superview**
 **- Equal width to superview**(if your container view is equal to superview).

Avoid setting leading and trailing constraint.Removing these two constraint resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can set width of its segment:

```
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.setWidth(widthItem, forSegmentAt: 0)
```